# Guard is being inconsistent with guard-sass, guard-haml and guard-coffee

Tags: coffeescript, sass, haml, guard

I want to have a single config for most of my projects. Where it searches for any sass, haml or coffee folders in my project folder. I do not want to update the config when I add a new place to make sass files.

starting folder stucture

```
 - sass
     - test.sass
 - coffee
     - test.coffee
 - haml
     - test.html.haml
 - a
     - folder
         - somewhere 
             - deep
                 - sass
                     - test2.sass
                 - coffee
                     - test2.coffee
                 - haml
                     - test2.html.haml
 - Guardfile
```

Wanted folder structure with generated files and folders:

```
 - sass
     - test.sass
 - css
     - test.css
 - coffee
     - test.coffee
 - js
     - test.js
 - haml
     - test.html.haml
 - test.html
 - a
     - folder
         - somewhere 
             - deep
                 - sass
                     - test2.sass
                 - css
                     - test2.css
                 - coffee
                     - test2.coffee
                 - js
                     - test2.js
                 - haml
                     - test2.html.haml
                 - test2.html
 - Guardfile
```

So far haml works flawlessly with

```
guard :haml, input: 'haml' do
  watch(/^.+(\.html\.haml)$/)
end
```

And sass, coffeescript work differently with the exact same code

```
guard :coffeescript, input: 'coffee', output: 'js' do 
  watch(/^.+(\.coffee)$/) 
end 

guard :sass, input: 'sass', output: 'css' do
  watch(/^.+(\.sass)$/)
end
```

The end result leads to placing destination css and js folder in the root of the projectfolder. Even when I remove the `output:` attribute it will make a coffee and sass folder at the root.

Result folder structure

```
 - sass
     - test.sass
 - css
     - test.css
     - test2.css
 - coffee
     - test.coffee
 - js
     - test.js
     - test2.js
 - haml
     - test.html.haml
 - test.html
 - a
     - folder
         - somewhere 
             - deep
                 - sass
                     - test2.sass
                 - coffee
                     - test2.coffee
                 - haml
                     - test2.html.haml
                 - test2.html
 - Guardfile
```

I have no idea what's going on, can somebody enlighten me?

Using Guard version 2.6.1

Answer (score 0):

Every plugin has it's own idea of how directories should be interpreted/used.

In coffeescript, there's a "trick" to tell it the output directory, by putting the input directory part in a regexp group, e.g.:

```
guard :coffeescript, input: 'coffee', output: 'js' do
  watch(/^(.+)\\.coffee$/)
end
```

But I'm guessing this will create e.g. `js/a/folder/somewhere/deep`, while you want `a/folder/somewhere/deep/js`.

If you don't specify the output dir, you'd probably get: `a/folder/somewhere/deep` - which is close, but doesn't have the `/js/` folder at the end.

In fact, Haml files a different, because while you want `(...)coffee/test2.coffee` to end up as `(...)/js/test2.js`, you expect `(...)/haml/test2.html.haml` to end up as `(...)/test2.html.haml`, and not `(...)/html/test2.html.haml` (meaning: you don't want it in a `html` subfolder - which I agree would be silly)...

... which means `guard-haml` is the exception here in what you expect from other plugins.

So the short story is:

you can't expect `guard-coffeescript` and `guard-sass` to behave like `guard-haml, because at the same time you're expecting them to *not* behave the same way (no`html`output folder for`.haml` files - which is obviously understandable).

In haml works like you want *only* because you didn't provide an `:output` option for it (try it and see what happens).

Meanwhile, `guard-coffeescript` has been updated (by me) to work with a newer version of guard, so the template is a bit different now and you'd probably need:

```
input_dir = 'a/folder/somewhere/deep'

coffeescript_options = {
  input: "#{input_dir}/coffee,
  output: "#{input_dir}/js",
  patterns: [%r{^#{input_dir}/(.+\.(?:coffee|coffee\.md|litcoffee))$}]
}

guard 'coffeescript', coffeescript_options do
  coffeescript_options[:patterns].each { |pattern| watch(pattern) }
end
```

`guard-sass` isn't updated for newer versions of Guard yet (in fact, it's never been migrated to Guard 2.0), so I won't even bother to investigate.

The choices I see are:

- make changes to guard-coffeescript to do what you want (reverse input/output folder order)
- reorganize your structure (probably recommended and faster)

Since a Guardfile is pure ruby, you have the option of iterating - if that helps, e.g.:

```
# I don't know which parts of the structure are projects, so I'm guessing it's the first part
Dir[*].each do |project|
  next unless File.directory?(project)
  next if %w(sass css coffee js).include?(project) #(skip top level non-project folders)
  input_dir = "#{project}/a/folder/somewhere/deep"

  coffeescript_options = {
    input: "#{input_dir}/coffee,
    output: "#{input_dir}/js",
    patterns: [%r{^#{input_dir}/(.+\.(?:coffee|coffee\.md|litcoffee))$}]
  }

  guard 'coffeescript', coffeescript_options do
    coffeescript_options[:patterns].each { |pattern| watch(pattern) }
  end

  # guard 'sass' would go here with a similar setup
end
```